# Oracle query optimisation max aggregate not using index

Tags: oracle, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table "AvoirStatuts" that's defined like this :
[image]

this is an association table for two other table , the foreign keys are 'num_compte' and 'id_statut'

I have a query (I created a view here )  to select the latest status for all accounts like this :

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "HR"."ETATACTUELCOMPTES"  
 ("id_statut", "num_compte") AS 
      select r2."id_statut",r2."num_compte" from 
            (
              select "num_compte",max("createdAt") createdAt 
              from "AvoirStatuts" 
              group by "num_compte"
            ) r1, "AvoirStatuts" r2 
            where 
               r1."num_compte"=r2."num_compte" 
               and r1.createdAt=r2."createdAt";
```

i want to speed up this query with indexes so i created an index like this

```
  create index creation_index on "AvoirStatuts" 
       ("num_compte","createdAt" desc );
```

but the query is not using that index i don't know why !

[image]

Comment: How many rows do you have in the "AvoirStatuts" table? If there's only a  few the optimizer may decide that it's faster to read the entire table and scan it than to use an index. The FULL TABLE SCAN operation in the plan only has a cost of 5, so it's going to be tough to improve on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this index:

```
create index covering_index on "AvoirStatuts" 
       ("num_compte","createdAt", "id_statut");
```